# Book with a magical school in a castle that might have “chronicles” in the title

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

In late elementary-early middle school I read this series I got from the scholastic reader pamphlet. I can't remember what it was titled to save my life. It may have had "chronicles" in the title. It read kind of like a generic Harry Potter. It had a magical school that was a castle, but I think it also involved Knight training and quests. I loved it at the time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any more details you can [edit] into your question.  We have no idea what years you were in middle school, for instance.

Comment: In particular, one easy upgrade would be to tell us what year range you were talking about, and whether the book was old or new at the time.  If you know exactly what company was producing the "scholastic reader pamphlet", that would also be a help.

Comment: @BenBarden: I believe the OP is referring to the "catalogues" put out by [Scholastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholastic_Corporation).

Comment: Could it have been *The Chronicles of Narnia*? It's got magic and castles and children, but only one book involves a (nonmagical) school and only for the first and last couple of chapters. Or perhaps the *Enchanted Forest Chronicles*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_Forest_Chronicles ? *A Wizard of Earthsea* also features a school for wizards, if that sounds familiar? Two other series that might be what you're looking for are *The Chronicles of Prydain* or the *Caster Chronicles*.

Comment: After searching into it, it may have been The Rangers Apprentice. But after reading the plot something still feels off about it. My memories of the series are vague. I keep trying to picture the book cover and visually it's similar to Percy Jackson and the Lightning Thief cover.

Comment: @Kaylah Going off the Percy Jackson thing, how 'bout this: http://rickriordan.com/series/kane-chronicles/ ?

Comment: The Charlie Bone books maybe? I doubt it was the Ranger's Apprentice since that series didn't have magic.

Comment: I'd agree with Alan Mills except Charlie Bone didn't really have knight training or quests, but certainly had magic and Harry Potterish adventures and characters. So it *could* be that too. Maybe looking at some of my suggestions will help jog your memory a little; if they don't, I'd still encourage you to check out at least Narnia, Prydain, and Earthsea if you're unfamiliar with those series. :D

Answer (score 2):

Under the heading of possible conflation of sources, Scholastic Press put out *[The Secret Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9297525-the-secret-kingdom)* in 2011, first book of *Chronicles of the Red King*, which is about the ancestor of Charlie Bone, who was sent to a magic school in his first book, [*Midnight for Charlie Bone*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9475.Midnight_for_Charlie_Bone).

[image: Cover of *The Secret Kingdom*] [image: Cover of *Midnight for Charlie Bone*]

Comment: If one of us provides the right answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't have "Chronicles" in the title, The *Circle of Magic* series by Debra Doyle and James D. Macdonald fits plotwise. In the first book, *[School of Wizardry](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363042.School_of_Wizardry)*, we encounter Randal, a squire in his Uncle's household, training to eventually become a knight, who instead goes with the wizard Madoc to learn magic at a school which, yes, is in a castle. The book was first published by Troll Communications (a company that Scholastic acquired), and later, Scholastic published a copy of it.

[image: 1990 edition of *School of Wizardry* by Troll Communications]
[image: 2000 edition of *School of Wizardry* by Troll Communications]
[image: Scholastic version of *School of Wizardry*]